# Telegram bot обработка запросов пользователя по очередно

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, очередь-задач

Ситуация - бот принимает запрос от пользователя и начинает его обрабатывать.
процесс не быстрый около минуты
в это время пользователь еще кидает запросы
бот начинает обрабатывать все вперемешку - в общем каша
Вопрос как привязать очередность к хендлеру обработки ?
в идеале пользователь кидает несколько значений на проверку и бот **последовательно** обрабатывает и **последовательно** скидывает готовые данные

```
import telebot
from selenium import webdriver
bot = telebot.TeleBot( "токен" )

def check(message):
--код--

bot.infinity_polling( True )
```

Comment: Я бы в базе данных хранил инфу и состоянии. Если у вас несколько запросов и должны в определенном порядке выполняться, это можно в базе для юзера хранить и ругаться, если при текущем состоянии происходит что-то, что доступно только для следующего

Comment: состояния это аиограм же ? - да бд в планах как и уход с телебота

Answer (score 0):

попробуй использовать декоратор

import telebot
from selenium import webdriver
bot = telebot.TeleBot( "токен" )

@dec
def check(message):
--код--
#если ошибка то попробуй @bot.message_handler(commands или content_types смотря что тебе нужно)

bot.infinity_polling( True )

Comment: Конкатенация немного сошла с ума поэтому вот

@dec
 def check(message):
 --код-- #если ошибка то попробуй @bot.message_handler(commands или content_types смотря что тебе нужно вместо @dec)

Comment: в общем я не знаю как тут показать ее нормально, прости пожалуйста но думаю ты понял

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).